# (Python) Networkx - Change Node Size dependent on value

Tags: python, size, nodes, networkx

i have an array like:

```
A = [104, 234, 543, 456, 346]
```

I want to draw the nodes of the list with:

```
nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G, pos, nodelist=A, node_size=?, node_color='red', node_shape='s', alpha=1)
```

But i want to have the node size dependent on the value the node has.
How is that possible?

Thank you in advance,
Greetings :)

Answer (score 3):

Reading [documentation](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.7/reference/generated/networkx.drawing.nx_pylab.draw_networkx_nodes.html) :

> node_size : scalar or array
>
> ```
> Size of nodes (default=300). If an array is specified it must be the same length as nodelist.
> ```

I guess that you just need to create array of nodes and array of sizes (that you determine depending on values) and pass them as parameters.

Example :

```
nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G, pos, nodelist=A, node_size=A, node_color='red', node_shape='s', alpha=1)
```

---

Tried this code :

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
g = nx.Graph()
A = [104, 234, 543, 456, 346]
g.add_nodes_from(A)
nx.draw_networkx_nodes(g, pos=nx.spring_layout(g), nodelist=A, node_size=A)
plt.show()
```

Got :

[image]

Comment: If i use `node_size = list(map(lambda n: n.weight*100, nodelist))`, i get the error `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "hypergraph.py", line 102, in <module>
    node_size = list(map(lambda n: n.weight*10, countermfi))
  File "hypergraph.py", line 102, in <lambda>
    node_size = list(map(lambda n: n.weight*10, countermfi))
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'weight'`

Comment: My mistake, I don't like how networkx gives ids instead of objects when you ask for nodes. I edited. @QWERASDFYXCV

Comment: What u mean with attribute name? It's only a list of integers, no dictionary or key fields in it.

Comment: "But i want to have the node size dependent on the value the node has" is unclear. For you, node id = node value ?

Comment: Ah yeah sorry, that was unclear. In my case node id = node value. But i want to scale the value to a fitting value for node_size.

Comment: @QWERASDFYXCV `A` values look fine for node_size. Add example

Comment: Yeah ok, but if i want to scale the size of the nodes according to their id/value with ur previous solution? `node_size = list(map(lambda n: n*10, A))` would work?